# Правильный запрос в MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once ('../function.php');

    $db = new Database;
    class checkSearch    
    {
        public $search;

        function postSearch($serach)
        {
            return $this->search = $_POST['search'];
        }

        function trimSearch($search)
        {
            return $this->search = trim($this->postSearch($search));
        }

        function stripSearch($search)
        {
            return $this->serach = strip_tags($this->trimSearch($search));
        }
    }

    $search = new checkSearch;
    echo '<table>';

    foreach($db->select('offices', '*', '', 'number_office LIKE ' . $search->stripSearch($_POST)) as $values)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($values as $key => $value)
        {
            echo '<td class="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Добрый день. В данном запросе к базе данных, хочу реализовать поиск по ключу LIKE и поиску любого значения при помощи аргумента %. Только вот везде в примерах приводят запись вида:

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'
```

Как этот аргумент добавить в моём случае?

Comment: Ух, нагородили... Во-первых у вас проблемы с ООП, во-вторых, сначала получаем данные, а потом работаем с ними в цикле, а то у вас в цикле куча запросов к БД, в-третьих, `$db->select('offices', '*', '', 'number_office LIKE %' . $search->stripSearch($_POST) . '%'`, в-четвертых, http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html

Comment: @DaemonHK, не работает Ваш "код"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел из положения таким образом:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once ('../function.php');

$db = new Database;

class checkSearch

  {
    public $search;

    function postSearch($serach)
      {
        return $this->search = $_POST['search'];
      }
    function trimSearch($search)
      {
        return $this->search = trim($this->postSearch($search) . '%');
      }
    function stripSearch($search)
      {
        return $this->serach = strip_tags($this->trimSearch($search));
      }
  }
$search = new checkSearch;
echo '<table>';
foreach($db->select('offices', '*', '', 'number_office LIKE ' . "'" .$search->stripSearch($_POST) . "'") as $values)
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($values as $key => $value)
      {
        echo '<td class="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</td>';
      }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Благодаря примеру @DaemonHK

Comment: Я мог `%` не там поставить, вечно путаю. Подробнее можно почитать тут -  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 1):

Хуже класса Database здесь только класс checkSearch.
Оба отправляем на свалку истории, и учимся работать с БД через PDO.

pdo.php берем [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql), заменив параметры подключения на свои

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once ('../function.php');
require_once ('../pdo.php');

$search = trim($_POST['search'])."%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * offices WHERE number_office LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$search]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
<?php foreach($data) as $values): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($values as $key => $value): ?>
        <td class="<?= htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

если интересно почитать про класс Database, вот [список граблей, на которые наступают начинающие писатели классов для работы с базой данных](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). Если плохо с английским, можно использовать https://www.deepl.com/ru/translator